# How compiler differentiate between prefix and postfix (increment and decrement) operator overloading with a dummy parameter in c++

Tags: c++

We know that, compiler differentiate between prefix and postfix operator overloading (increment and decrement) in c++ with a dummy parameter.

let's consider the following increment operator overloading examples.

```
class Chocolate
{
    private: int countChocolate;

    public: Chocolate()
    {
        countChocolate = 0;
    }

    public: Chocolate& operator++()
    {
        ++countChocolate;

        return *this;
    }

    public: Chocolate operator++(int)
    {
        Chocolate temp(countChocolate);

        ++(*this); 

        return temp;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Chocolate kitkat;

    ++kitkat; // this will call the prefix

    kitkat++; // this will call the postfix

    return 0;
}
```

Now, my question is how compiler differentiate between them with a dummy parameter

**how the differentiate procedure happen within the compiler**

because I am not passing **any parameter** in either approach then how and why it differentiate between the both operators

because in my sense

++kitkat and kitkat++ both will be translate to

kitkat.operator++();

so,

how it works in depth within the compiler

can anyone told me that in detail

I am just curious.

Comment: @melpomene but all the answers in there don't explain how the procedure happen, it just saying we need the dummy operator for differentiate between prefix and postfix, I already know that, my question is how this differentiate procedure happen within compiler

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how a C++ compiler works?

Comment: yeah, in this particular problem

Comment: What problem? I don't get what exactly is unclear.

Comment: @melpomene actually I am trying to understand how and why the compiler differentiate between prefix and postfix ++ because, i am not passing any parameters in any case like kitkat++7, cause it's using a dummy parameter, so I am guessing I have to pass something even though for differentiate reason

Comment: Just because YOU don't pass a parameter value does not mean the COMPILER does not.  The compiler knows the position of the `++` relative to the variable name, so `++kitkat` would be called by the compiler like `kitkat.operator++()` whereas `kitkat++` would be called like `kitkat.operator++(0)` (or whatever value the compiler wants to use, the actual value is irrelevant).

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks man, that's the answer I am looking for

Comment: And it's not in the previous questions